# iPad: how many space to store data locally?

Tags: xcode, ipad, store

sorry, perhaps my for my English I can't find the right answer. If the question already exists close my question.

I'm about to start a new big project, an iPad app that will use a whole bunch of data including images, PDF files and variables in general and I'm thinking about storing all the data locally (in Sql Lite).

I was wondering how many data can I save on an iPad? Can I use all the hard disk space (based on the different measures of disk of each different iPad)??

Thanks

Comment: it depends on what device you bought: the `16GB`, the `32GB` or the `64GB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your Question -- **I was wondering how many data can I save on an iPad? Can I use all the hard disk space (based on the different measures of disk of each different iPad)??**

Yes, You surely can. All remaining free (Available) space of iPad is available to your iOS App.

Useful link for your reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah Go to above link and check

Answer (score 0):

The app cannot be bigger than 2GB on the App Store but once downloaded and installed you can add as much additional data to it as you want.